# Problems with array changing elements

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, element

I am trying to change elements in an array to the word "empty" with a Jbutton and also add names through a Jtextfield if the in the selected position in the array says empty. For some reason I cant get it to work. here is the code don't know if I am missing something or I am just completely wrong

```
move = new JButton("Add Tennant");
window.add(move);
moveIn.addActionListener(this);

Tennant = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
nTennant.setText("Enter new name") ;
window.add(Tennant);
Tennant.addActionListener(this);

evict = new JButton("Evict");
window.add(evict);
moveIn.addActionListener(this);
```

different method:

```
if(e.getSource() == move)
{
    if (occupant[selectedApartment].equals("empty"))
    {
        occupant[selectedApartment] = Tennant.getText();
    }
}

if(e.getSource() == evict)
{
    if(!occupant[selectedApartment].equals("Empty"))
    {
        occupant[selectedApartment] = "Empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is you use `occupant[selectedApartment] = "Empty";` to set an apartment empty, but use `if (occupant[selectedApartment].equals("empty"))` to test if an apartment is empty

`"Empty" != "empty"`

You could change

```
if (occupant[selectedApartment].equals("empty"))
```

to

```
if (occupant[selectedApartment].equals("Empty"))
```

or use

```
if (occupant[selectedApartment].equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
```

or change

```
occupant[selectedApartment] = "Empty";
```

to

```
occupant[selectedApartment] = "empty";
```

Comment: I used if (occupant[selectedApartment].equalsIgnoreCase("empty")) and that worked but still working on the evict function